# vieux the data to modify firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display the data of an element before to be able to modify it.

I have a Firebase database as follows:

[image]

I wish to retrieve the information of this JSON on my page single address but I do not know how to do it to do it because I am new in angular and firebase. below my different codes

Adress list html

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items;" (click)="editItem(item.key)">
      <div><b>{{item.prenom}} {{item.nom}}</b></div>
    </ion-card>
```

Address list .ts (method)

```
 editItem(key){

    const UserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('adresse');
    var adaRef = usersRef.child(UserId);
    var adaFirstNameRef = adaRef.child(key);
    var path = adaFirstNameRef.toString();
    console.log(path);

    this.router.navigate(['single-adresse/' +key]);


  }
```

how to get the data on the unique address page. if you have examples I'm interested
I can recover the JSON link from firebase thanks to the child.
[image]

Comment: Could you please tell did my answer help?

Comment: the code works very well. I know if it's possible to ask you one last thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will work for getting specific json(data) of specific child.

```
const UserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('adresse');
var adaRef = usersRef.child(UserId);

// new code 
adaRef.child(key).on("value",(snapshot)=>{
    // will print specifc json of your child's key (address,commune,nom etc.)
    console.log("values are ",snapshot.val()) 
});
```